# LibGit2Sharp equivalent of 'git cherry'

Tags: libgit2sharp

As instructed by the project's [wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki), here I am.

**How can I detect if commits exist that have not yet been pushed to the
remote using LibGit2Sharp?**

Git's [way](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) would be: `git cherry` but I can't seem to find an equivalent.

I can see, however, that cherry picking [exists](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/b399005e901e01ed126b874c9a8a9c3954c20a28) in LibGit2Sharp. Would there be a workaround using that in lieu of `git cherry`?